# error 87: wmfile option is not recognized in this context

Tags: windows-7, usb, windows-installation

I'm trying to reinstall windows 7 via USB 3.0 as my laptop has no USB 2.0 slots. I'm trying to follow the [steps here](http://codeabitwiser.com/2014/03/how-to-install-windows-7-with-only-usb-3-0-ports/). See where I hit my error below:

[image]

Stumped as to why it isn't working. Here is [my log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3eRv-4znU32OGRqaGl6QkFMU0U/view?usp=sharing)

I did run cmd as admin and the drivers I moved to the "USB3" folder are [these](http://downloads.eurocom.com/support/drivers/zip/331/331_USB3_W764.zip). My USB stick where the windows 7 image is should not be corrupt as I just made a new one (though it might help, it didn't). My windows 7 licence is also recently purchased if that changes anything.

Comment: Try this utility when making your W7 install disc...https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25476/Windows-7-USB-3-0-Creator-Utility

Comment: Ran into another bloody issue after Moab's solution fixed this one. Afterwards I retried the W7 install disc for a third time but this time on a different laptop and presto, finally!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your mistake

you used wmfile instead of the correct syntax wimfile

correct string should be

> C:\Users\Cole\Desktop\USB3 Fix>dism /mount-wim /**wimfile**:boot.wim /index:2 /mountdir:mount